# Get unique elements from each list in list of lists

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of lists populated with integers. These integers represent nodes in a graph and the lists in the main list represent cycles in the graph. I want to extract a unique set of nodes - one node from each cycle - in the order of the list of lists.

**Example:**

I know, it's not possible to have a cycle with only two nodes, but it is the easiest non trivial example i came up with and it should make clear what I am looking for.

```
cycles = [[11, 22, 55], [22, 44], [11, 33], [22, 33]]
result = [11, 44, 33, 22]
```

Another possible result would be `[22, 44, 11, 33]`

**My Solution:**

What i tried till now is using `itertools.product`, to run thorugh all combinations of elements from the list of lists until i find a set with the same length as the number of lists in my main list.

```
def find_random_unique_combination_from_cycles(cycles):
    only_one = dict()
    for ci, cy in enumerate(cycles):
        for element in cy:
            if len([element for cyc in cycles if element in cyc]) == 1:
                only_one.update({element: ci})

    prod_cycles = [cycle for ci, cycle in enumerate(cycles) if ci not in only_one.values()]
    cycle_length = len(prod_cycles)
    result = []
    for combi in it.product(*prod_cycles, repeat=1):
        if len(set(combi)) == cycle_length:
            result = list(combi)
            break
    for element, index in only_one.items():
        result.insert(index, element)
    return result
```

**The Problem:**

This solution works quite well for the example above and similar cases. But for larger graphs with more and larger cycles, it doesn't find a solution in an appropriate runtime (i had to stop execution for a list containing ~200 cycles). I also tried to reduce the size of the list of lists by removing all cycles which have only one unique element, but it didn't help that much.
Is there a better and faster way to find a single unique element from each list of lists?

Help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define `Uniqueness`? why `11` instead of `22`? It can be 22 instead of 11?

Comment: Another possible result would be:  [22, 44, 11, 33]

Comment: I don't know if solution is efficient

Comment: list(set([item for l in cycles for item in l]))

Comment: Thanks! My example wasn't precise enough! I edited it... In this case you would have more unique elements than cycles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a recursive generator approach carrying the set of used numbers to the next level of recursion:

```
def getPath(cycles,used=None):
    if not cycles: yield [];return  # end of path
    if used is None: used = set()   # track used numbers
    for n in cycles[0]:             # take from first sub list
        if n in used: continue      # skip used, recurse, tagging used n
        yield from ([n]+p for p in getPath(cycles[1:],used|{n}))
```

output:

```
cycles = [[11, 22, 55], [22, 44], [11, 33], [22, 33]]

for path in getPath(cycles): print(path)

[11, 44, 33, 22]
[22, 44, 11, 33]
[55, 22, 11, 33]
[55, 44, 11, 22]
[55, 44, 11, 33]
[55, 44, 33, 22]
```

If you want the paths to come out at random, you can add this line at the beginning of the function (and import the random module):

```
if used is None: cycles = [random.sample(c,len(c)) for c in cycles]
```

This will allow you to use the next() function to obtain a random path without having to go through all combinations:

```
randomPath = next(getPath(cycles))
```

*Note that the generator uses a naive, brute force, traversal.  There is room for optimization.*

*For example, there could be a check that the distinct unused numbers in the cycles are enough to cover the number of sublists. This would allow earlier short-circuiting of traversal branches.*

```
...
if len(set().union(*cycles)-used)<len(cycles): return
for n in cycles[0]:
    ...
```

*Or, the used numbers could be removed from the cycles lists on each level of recursion.*

```
def getPath(cycles):
    if not cycles: yield [];return  # end of path
    if not all(cycles): return      # no path when there is an empty sublist
    for n in cycles[0]:             # take from first sub list
        nextCycles = [ [r for r in c if r!=n] for c in cycles[1:] ]
        yield from ( [n] + p for p in getPath(nextCycles) )
```

Comment: That looks great! Thank you so much! I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
cycles = [[11, 22], [22, 44], [11, 33], [22, 33]]
from itertools import product
a=list(product(*cycles))
[list(i) for i in a if len(i) == len(set(i))]
```

Output:

```
[[11, 44, 33, 22], [22, 44, 11, 33]]
```

You can check out [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/tutorial.html) Module if you are into efficiency .

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
cycles = [(11, 22), (22, 44), (11, 33), (22, 33)]
G.add_edges_from(cycles)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
G.nodes
```

[image: The Graph]

`G.nodes` returns `NodeView((11, 22, 44, 33))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the case of large graphs with more larger cycles this does not help! I get a memory error

Comment: I used networkx to extract the cycles from a graph. But i only need a single unique node from each cycle.